# Changing a Controls Property

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

There is something not going out of my head because i spent now several days to get an **understandable** answer with reading books and searching the web.

In my VS 2012 VB.net project I have a usercontrol that contains a toolstrip. The toolstrip has a toolstripdropdownbutton with a toolstripmenuitem in it. I drag this usercontrol onto a windows form. **My aim** is to change the text of the menuitem when I'am in the forms designer mode.

I tried to create some properties in the usercontrol for example

```
public property TS as Toolstrip
 get
   return Toosltrip1
 end get
 set (value as Toolstrip)
  Toolstrip1 = value
 end set
```

Doing so I can open the toolbar item collection in the property grid of the usercontrol on the windows form using the new usercontrols property TS and I am able to change the menuitems text 
but when I run the windows form the old text of the menuitem is displayed and my **property change is ignored**.

What should I do so that the property change is not ignored.

Please help me to clear my head with this problem .

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only changing the text, use this property instead :

```
Public Property MenuText As String
    Get
        Return ToolStripMenuItem1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ToolStripMenuItem1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: @LarsTech Actually I just tried it with `ToolStripDropDownButton` and it worked?

Comment: I'm having a rough morning.